# Decipher this .htaccess line

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

```
# Redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.([a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]**
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Ok, so in the above code I think the 1st line says "if the URL does not have www." and then the 3rd line says to "rewrite the URL with the www. as a 301 redirect", but the 2nd line I believe is to take into consideration subdomains and exclude them, but can anyone tell me what this `!\.([a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$`says exactly?

Another question: if `mod_rewrite` is enabled do I still need to add `RewriteEngine On`to the top of the `.htaccess` file? What happens if I don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression on the second line matches, if the string:

- `!` does not have
- `\.` a literal dot, followed by
- `[a-z-]` multiple characters of the a-z,- range, followed by
- `\.` another literal dot, followed by
- `[a-z]{2,6}` between 2 and 6 characters from the a-z range
- `$` before the end of the string

The parenthesis "(..)" allow capturing of a matched substring.
This can then be used in following expression/substitutions.

The `NC` flag will cause the match to performed case-insensitive.

In your case this will trigger a rewrite if the incoming URL

- does not start with `www.` (1st line)
- does not end with sth that looks like `.hostname.tld` (2nd line)

See https://regex101.com/ for a good playground to experiment with regular expressions.